# How to Prove this Set Question?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

For both sets C and D, provide a proof that C ∪ (D − /C) = C

"/C" is a set's complement of C

Comment: What are your thoughts? Is this homework?

Comment: Nope just a review problem that I'm trying to prove and I have no idea what's going on in this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in C$, then clearly $x\in C\cup (D- C^{c})=A$ and so $C\subset A$. Now let $x\in A$. Then there are three possibilities. Either 1) $x\in C$ and $x\notin D- C^{c}$ or 2) $x\in D- C^{c}$ and $x\notin C$ or 3) $x$ is in both of these sets. For 1) and 3) it is clear that $x\in C$. For 2) observe that $x\in D-C^{c}$ means that $x\in D$ and $x\notin C^{c}$ and hence again $x\in C$ and so in all the three cases $A\subset C$. Thus $A=C$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You need to prove $C\cup (D\setminus C^c)\subset C$ and $C\subset C\cup (D\setminus C^c)$. (I write $C^c$ for the complement of $C$, while $A\setminus B$ is $A$ minus $B$, that is the elements of $A$ that are not part of $B$).

In general to prove $A\subset B$ one must prove: for each $x\in A$ we have $x\in B$.